# What is the explanation behind the key combinations to enlarge and decrease font size in terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

To enlarge my font size in Terminal, I use `CTRL SHIFT +`. To decrease the font size, I hit `CTRL -`. Why is this not consistent ? i.e. why is SHIFT not required for decreasing the font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default its actually <kbd>Ctrl +</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl -</kbd>.

Depending on your keyboard layout you'll need <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get a `+`, like on a US keyboard, where `+` is <kbd>Shift =</kbd>. On such a keyboard <kbd>Ctrl +</kbd> is actually <kbd>Ctrl Shift =</kbd>.

Comment: That makes sense